# React FC Component - Display Name

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to create a packages like react-bootstrap.

```
<Card>

<Card.Title>Hello</Card.Title>

</Card>
```

I wish to create like below. But I couldn't able to do.

```
<MyCustomComponent>
<MyCustomComponent.Header>
Header goes here
</MyCustomComponent.Header>
</MyCustomComponent>
```

```
interface Props {
 children?: React.ReactNode | React.ReactNode[]
}

export const MyCustomComponent:FC<Props> = () => { 

}
```

Props throwing error like .Header does not exist on type `FC<Props & { children?: ReactNode; }>`

React Version: ^18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know in React > 18 children props was deleted from React.FC and you are able to use **PropsWithChildren** type (import it from React) like this:

```
const MyComponent: React.FC<PropsWithChildren<Props>> => …
```

And then to achieve the approach you want, you can follow like this:

```
const Header: React.FC = () => …
const Content: React.FC = () => …

const MyCustomComponent = {Header, Content};
export default MyCustomComponent;
```

And in other components, you can use it like this:

```
import MyCustomComponent …
…
<MyCustomComponent.Header />
<MyCustomComponent.Content />
```

Comment: I think this one was really good. But Is there way to wrap a component inside like below.<MyCustomComponent > <MyCustomComponent .Header /> <.MyCustomComponent>

Answer (score 1):

### Check React-bootstrap as reference of your code

Below code is from [react-bootstrap's form component](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/Form.tsx) :

```
export default Object.assign(Form, {
  Group: FormGroup,
  Control: FormControl,
  Floating: FormFloating,
  Check: FormCheck,
  Switch,
  Label: FormLabel,
  Text: FormText,
  Range: FormRange,
  Select: FormSelect,
  FloatingLabel,
});
```

As you see, React-bootstrap is using `Object.assign` function to assign differential components to `Form` Component.

So, in your case code should be:

```
export default Object.assign(MyCustomComponent, {
  Header: MyCustomComponentHeader,
});
```

Check [MDN's `Object.assign()` document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for more.

Answer (score 0):

I would make `MyCustomComponent` require all of it's children as props, and add them all to the `MyCustomComponent` as a property, like so:

```js
// MyCustomComponent.tsx

import { ReactNode } from 'react';
import Header from './MyCustomComponentHeading';

type Props = {
  header: ReactNode;
};

const MyCustomComponent = ({ header }: Props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>My Custom Component</h1>
      {header}
    </>
  );
};

// this is the magical step. Add as many components as you want like this.
MyCustomComponent.Header = Header;

export default MyCustomComponent;
```

```js
// MyCustomComponentHeading.tsx

type Props = {
  heading: string;
};

const Header = ({ heading }: Props) => {
  return <h2>{heading}</h2>;
};

export default Header;
```

It would then be consumed like this:

```js
// App.tsx

import MyCustomComponent from '../library/MyCustomComponent';


export const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <MyCustomComponent
        header={<MyCustomComponent.Header heading="My Custom Heading" />}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

**Suggested improvement - use the Context API**

I would additionally recommend using the Context API to ensure that these children components are only rendered within their parent.

For a full working example that includes a custom context, [check out this stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-eyoyec?file=src%2Fconsumer%2FApp.tsx).

**Youtube Video**

This answer has been strongly guided by [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPRdY87_SH0) which I highly recommend giving a watch, to properly understand how the custom context can be utilised.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the supports. This what I have done and it works as expected.

```
export const App = () => {
  return (
    <MyCustomComponent>
      <MyCustomComponent.Header>
              Header Content
      </MyCustomComponent.Header>

      <MyCustomComponent.Footer>
             Footer Content
      </MyCustomComponent.Footer>
    </MyCustomComponent>
  );
};
```

in MyCustomComponent.tsx

```
const CustomHeader: FC<PropsWithChildren> = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <div className='custom-header'>{children}</div>
    )
};

const CustomFooter: FC<PropsWithChildren> = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <div className='custom-footer'>{children}</div>
    )
};

const MyCustomComponent: FC<PropsWithChildren> = ({children}) => {
   return children;
});

MyCustomComponent.Header = CustomHeader;

MyCustomComponent.Footer = CustomFooter;
 

export default MyCustomComponent;
```